# Is it possible to get macOS commercial system name?

Tags: swift, macos

Right now I'm using code like this:

```
func osVersion() -> String {
    let osVersion = Foundation.ProcessInfo.processInfo.operatingSystemVersion
    let majorVersion = osVersion.majorVersion
    let minorVersion = osVersion.minorVersion

    if majorVersion == 10 && minorVersion == 10 {
        return "Yosemite"
    } else if majorVersion == 10 && minorVersion == 11 {
       return "El Capitan"
    } else if majorVersion == 10 && minorVersion == 12 {
       return "Sierra"
    } else if majorVersion == 10 && minorVersion == 13 {
       return "High Sierra"
    } else {
       return "Unknown"
    }
}
```

But if it will be new update this code will be returning "Unknown"

So, is it possible to programmatically get system commercial name?

Comment: Unrelated suggestion, you can use switch on a tuple like this `switch (majorVersion, minorVersion) { case 10, 10: return "Yosemite" ... }`

Comment: Yea, you're right, it will be more Swifty =)

Comment: Call me "Captain Kludge" if you like but it does appear in `system_profiler -detailLevel full > sp.txt` if you care to `grep/awk` it out... 

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't appear there =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple deprecated operatingSystemName Api from version 10.10.

In Foundation > NSProcessInfo > ProcessInfo

```
@available(OSX, introduced: 10.0, deprecated: 10.10, message: "-operatingSystemName always returns NSMACHOperatingSystem, use -operatingSystemVersionString instead")

open func operatingSystemName() -> String
```

The suggested api from its comment only return version string something as "Version 10.13.1 (Build 17B1003)" instead of commercial name

```
open var operatingSystemVersionString: String { get }
```